# Run Falcon APP with uwsgi

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, uwsgi, falconframework

I just started to learn Falcon (http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)
but it need a web server running and docs suggesting use uwsgi or gunicorn.

though they have mentioned that how to use it with gunicorn

```
$ pip install gunicorn  #install
$ gunicorn things:app   #and run app through gunicorn.
```

But I want to run this sample app with uwsgi. but I have no clue how to.

I have installed it `pip install uwsgi` also `gevent` as suggested here http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install.html

but what now. somebody guide me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll probably find your answer on the uWSGI documentation site, specifically try this page:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

I've never used Falcon or uWSGI, but it looks like you can probably get away with:

```
uwsgi --wsgi-file things.py --callable app
```

Comment: this worked: `uwsgi --http :9000 --wsgi-file things.py --callable app`

Comment: A shorter version should also work, with `--module=things.app`

Answer (score 2):

You can use uwsgi.ini to store configuration and easy run. Good way to setup uwsgi as services. Configuration with virtualenv

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8000
chdir = /home/user/www/uwsgi-ini
virtualenv = /home/user/www/uwsgi-ini/venv/
wsgi-file = main.py
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```

and run in app folder:

```
uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

command with virtualenv

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file main.py --callable app -H $(pwd)/venv/
```